# Google Motion Chart not loading

Tags: google-chrome, charts, flash

At the following link, there is a motion chart example that is supposed to demonstrate how the motion chart works:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart#example

What I am getting is a blank space where the chart is supposed to be located. Tested on both Safari and Chrome with latest Flash Player installed. The OS used is Sierra Mac version 10.12.6

The Chrome Console does not show any errors.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Use Firefox. It works perfectly on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 60.0.1

Comment: Thanks David! I installed Firefox 60.0.1 for Mac and it worked perfectly. However, I still am looking to solve the issue with Chrome at least.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but apparently motion charts were in the process of being discontinued in Google Sheets. I would speculate that the package was also discontinued (I also can't see the example and I also can't run the code using Google Script).

Relevant thread: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/QoJBwHMPogI